# NodeJS sqlite3 get error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

How to get error message from "err" variable? When I dump that variable it contains

```
{ [Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: UNIQUE constraint failed: _test.Id] errno: 19, code: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT' }
```

I need to get "Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: UNIQUE constraint failed: _test.Id" from "err" variable. I'm executing this query.

```
db.run("INSERT INTO _test (Var1) VALUES (?)", '1', function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
});
```

Alredy tried err[0], print out all properties with "for", but it returns only "errorno" and "code" properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an exception object in JS. The message is stored in `err.message`. The console just prints out those square brackets when serializing objects; it's not an array.

Comment: Oh, yea. I's built-in [Error object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error). Thanks!